# "online" Event Phonegap Android failed to fire on StateChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

i need to upload some data on server when internet is connected its working fine but when internet is disconnected then i m saving all data in **localStorage** with unique **Id** and when internet connection is connected again then all those localStorage data will be upload on server.But right now my "**Online**" Event is not firing even i have OFF my WIFI from device then ON WIFI again.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);
         function onDeviceReady() 
{
          alert("device ready");
          checkConnection();
         document.addEventListener("online",callOnlineFunction, false);
}
        function checkConnection() 
{
        network = navigator.network.connection.type;
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';
        return states[network];
}
 function callOnlineFunction()
{ 
            alert("call onlione function");
           loginOnOnline();
           getDataFromQueue();
}

 function loginOnOnline()
{   
           checkConnection();
}
```

Comment: are you not getting this alert? alert("call onlione function");

Comment: i m getting this alert online first time   i should get this alert whenever i change event from offline to online

Comment: only give alert and comment rest of the code in callOnlineFunction() and check if you are getting alert..

Comment: can u please correct me ?

Comment: still its not firing while offline event (i have put for tested) it fires exactly when device goes offline

Comment: i have tested in android Samsung Galaxy S3(ANDROID 4.1.2)and in tablet CE0168(ANDROID 4.0.3)its working fine in ANDROID 4.1.2  WHILE NO (on online alert)  in android 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because of our ignorance of small things:

you haven't declared the states object

```
var states = {};
```

before using it for assigning the values.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is typo else i have alerady declares

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured device permissions you can refer- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection